# Set th or td height in HTML for one column

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying to set the `<th>` size for one column. I was trying something like

`<th width=100> Description </th>`

and the same for `<tr>` ( `<tr width=100>`)

The above does not resize the column at all.

Comment: @KickButtowski The column doesn't resize when I type 

`<th width=100> Description </th>`

Comment: `<th style="width: 100px;">Description</th>`

Comment: Show a minimal document that actually demonstrates the issue. My guess is that you are trying to set a column to 100 pixels when there is something in its content that requires a larger width (or other settings that make the column wider). The `width` property sets just a suggested *minimum* width.

Comment: Your title indicates `height` of `th` or `td` but you are actually trying to set `width`.Try this `<th height="100">Description</th>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to use an inline style inside your HTML tags. First off, I recommend quotes around your units of measure like so. `<th width="100"></th>` Also, you arent defining the units of measure of the tags. you can use: `<th width="100px"></th>` or `<th width="100%"></th>` i think that you can even do inches and centimeters. Be careful when using the inline style `length' as the webpage is limitless....

Another way you can do this is using CSS. Inside your head tag could be a `<style>` tag.
Inside you can do:
`.measure { width:100px; }` 
Note it doesn't have to be pixels. Then on any tag you want 100px wide, you just do:
`<th class="width"></th>` or `<tr class="measure"></tr>`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, `width="100px"` is incorrect, and the rest in the answer is irrelevant.